# How to avoid a race condition in Nodejs and Mongoose app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a routine to update a value in the DB and then look for it on a one second timer. Here is a simplistic setup...

```
function checkStatusAndDoWork(){
  userMongooseModel.find({'someCondition': { $gte:(new Date()) }}, function(err, userModel){
      if (userModel.length > 0) { //there is only one document in the return.
          doSomeWorkThatTakes20seconds();
          // Update the Mongo document with a new next time
          userMongooseModel.update( {_id:userModel[0]._id}, {'someCondition': Date.now() + 10000}, function(err, numAffected){ 
              console.log('Checkpoint 1'); 
              setTimeout(checkStatusAndDoWork, 1000); //repeat the loop after 1 second.
          })
      } else {
          console.log('Checkpoint 2');
          setTimeout(checkStatusAndDoWork, 1000); // otherwise repeat the loop after 1 second anyways.
      }
  }
}
```

The situation -

Normally, everything works OK. I see the following:

```
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 2
...
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 2
...
```

But if I open MongoExplorer and start reviewing the document, then I see the following if I happen to time it just right...

```
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 2
...
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 2
...
```

It appears that the update goes into a Mongo queue and so the document is not updated immediately. This causes the find() to return true and go to 'Checkpoint 1' repeatedly until the db write is complete.

**How can I avoid this race condition?**

Note: I rewrote this [How do I use setTimeout with double callbacks in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877300/how-do-i-use-settimeout-with-double-callbacks-in-javascript) question to simplify.

Comment: Is your `doSomeWorkThatTakes20seconds()` function sync or async? It might help to insert a timestamp into the log.

Comment: Regardless of whether `doSomeWorkThatTakes20Secs()` is sync or async if it is executed after `userMongooseModel.update` it may block JS execution thread for 20 secs, so `someCondition` is still valid on next `checkStatusAndDoWork` which theoretically should be executed after 1sec, but because event loop is blocked it is executed after e.g. 21secs.

Comment: Could you try to split `doSomeWorkThatTakes20Secs` into series of smaller tasks? You should not block events loop for so long. In browsers this is usually solved by recursive `setTimeout` calls, but I know that in Node.JS there's `process.nextTick` or something like that which is quicker.

Comment: I removed the dSoSomeWorkThatTakes20Secs() completely and replaced it with a dummy calls to some math functions: var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60*0.6) + 60*0.4; var waitTimeout = randomNum*10*1000;  Just for the fun of it. No change.

Comment: You replaced it and does the new funtion blocks execution for 20secs too? The question is - could you remove it completely or rewrite it in non-blocking way?

Comment: No more 20 sec blocking. But the results remain unchanged.

Comment: `new Date() + 10000` results in string concatenation. **also**, if your update actually succeeded in doing what it looks like it’s **intended** to do, your loop would never proceed to “Checkpoint 2” unless if the `setTimeout(checkStatusAndDoWork, 1000); //repeat the loop after 1 second.` was unable to run for roughly 10 seconds (because of the `$gte`). It would make sense if some sync code you don’t show ran long enough to prevent the setTimeout() callback from ticking (or maybe you’re running two instances of `checkStatusAndDoWork()`?).